# Should I add a "real-delete" method on DAO for integration test?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, dao

I am writing some integration tests for some legacy code. To ensure the functions behave as expected, I need to setup the fake data, invoke the testing APIs, then clean up the data.

Due to policy reason, we can only access the database via tools like Hibernate and MyBatis, never direct connection. However, our `delete()` method on the DAOs is always of the soft-deletion style (ie, turn on the `is_delete` flag.) So the clean-up actually just turns on the `is_delete` flag, and the fake data is still there!

So, should I add a "real-delete" method on the DAOs for the integration tests, or there's a better way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with adding a real delete method - after all, the point of an integration test is to test all the components together in an effort to emulate they way they will actually be used.

I would just make sure that if you do this, you first add records that you know will not be duplicates. Then you can assert that those records are present in the database, delete them, and assert that they are no longer present. That way you ensure that your test never deletes real data.